# TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

My unit test case started failing when I started running the unit test in mocha from karma,
Earlier we were using karma and --browser to run the test case but it was running fine,

```
  1) common/browser-detection
       returns the mock object when there is no userAgent:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (packages/node_modules/@webex/plugin-meetings/test/unit/spec/common/browser-detection.js:115:41)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21)

  2) plugin-meetings
       meeting index
         Public Api Contract
           #addMedia
             should reject promise if user already in left state:
     AssertionError: expected [ReferenceError: navigator is not defined] to be an instance of UserNotJoinedError
      at /Users/nswarnka/Documents/Neeraj/Projects/upstream/webex-js-sdk/packages/node_modules/@webex/plugin-meetings/test/unit/spec/meeting/index.js:763:20
```

Package.json

```
"test": "node ./tooling/index.js test",

 "circleci:local": "circleci local execute -c .circleci/github.config.yml",
```

test file -

It fails for navigator here, TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined

```
  it('returns the mock object when there is no userAgent', () => {
    Object.defineProperty(global.window.navigator, 'userAgent', {
      get: () => undefined,
      configurable: true
    });
```

ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

```
/**
 * proxy to browser navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
Media.getDevices = () => {
  if (navigator && navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices) {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  }

  return Promise.reject(new MediaError('enumerateDevices not supported.'));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing `global.window.navigator` is an error both in a browser (where `global` is not defined) and in Node.js (where there is no global `window` object, and also no `navigator`).

If that test were to run in a browser, you could just redefine the `userAgent` on `navigator` (or equivalently `window.navigator`), i.e.

```js
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
  get: () => undefined,
  configurable: true
});
```

But if you run that test in Node.js without a DOM emulation setup you will run into an error because `navigator` is undefined. You could mock `navigator` of course before mocking `userAgent`, but then for your test to pass you would also need to mock `navigator.mediaDevices` and `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices`, and in the end you would test nothing but the mock code itself.

Conclusion: use DOM emulation ([JSDom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom), [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/)) or run your test in a real browser with [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/latest/index.html) or [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).

Comment: Hi, I am using ```    "jsdom": "19.0.0",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2",``` as dev dependencies..

Comment: @JavascriptCoder in that case, the problem may be in your JSDom setup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71795973/jest-typeerror-addeventlistener-is-not-a-function-in-unit-test?noredirect=1#comment126876155_71795973  Can you help me with this issue ?