# jest TypeError: addEventListener is not a function in unit test

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using jest and my test framework,

My test case is failing for

```
TypeError: this[#mediaStreamTrack].addEventListener is not a function

      174 |         if (this.#isSubscribed !== true) {
      175 |           this.#isSubscribed = true;
    > 176 |           this.#mediaStreamTrack.addEventListener('mute', (event) => {
          |                                  ^
      177 |             trackMutePublisher(event, this, 'track');
      178 |           });
      179 |         }
```

In my test file, I have this code -

```
  it('should have subscribe, track mute event available', () => {
    expect(subscription.listener.method).toEqual(eventCallbackSpyTrack);
    expect(
      subscriptions.events['track:mute'].get(subscription.listener.id)?.method
    ).toEqual(eventCallbackSpyTrack);
    expect(subscription2.listener.method).toEqual(eventCallbackSpyTrack2);
    expect(
      subscriptions.events['track:mute'].get(subscription2.listener.id)?.method
    ).toEqual(eventCallbackSpyTrack2);
  });
```

I was trying to solve this by mocking this.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    console.log("track.getMediaStreamTrack() ",track.getMediaStreamTrack())
    track.getMediaStreamTrack().addEventListener = jest.fn();
    // #mediaSteamTrack.addEventListener = jest.fn();
  });
```

But this doesn't work.

`track.getMediaStreamTrack()` in class we have

```
 /**
   * This method returns the underlying MediaStreamTrack
   *
   * @returns #mediaStreamTrack of type MediaStreamTrack
   */
  getMediaStreamTrack(): MediaStreamTrack {
    logger.debug({
      mediaType: MEDIA,
      action: 'getMediaStreamTrack()',
      description: 'Called',
    });
    const mediaStreamTrack = this.#mediaStreamTrack;

    logger.debug({
      mediaType: MEDIA,
      action: 'getMediaStreamTrack()',
      description: `Received media stream track ${JSON.stringify(mediaStreamTrack)}`,
    });

    return mediaStreamTrack;
  }
```

Comment: That's probably because jest is using a virtual DOM which is does not have this property. So you could check, if you even get a proper object back from `track.getMediaStreamTrack()` or even mock the whole object as a `jest.fn()`

Comment: can you suggest the proper mock for ```track.getMediaStreamTrack()```

Comment: I am doing something like this ```const mockGetMediaStreamTrack = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockMediaStreamTrack);
        track.getMediaStreamTrack = mockGetMediaStreamTrack;```

Comment: I guess something like this

`let map = {}; <-- global somewhere`
`let mockMediaStream = undefined;
beforeEach( () => {
 mockMediaStream = {
  addEventListener: jest.fn((event, cb) => {
   map[event] = cb;
  })
 };
});`